# java ProcessBuilder external process wait not work well

Tags: java, process

i have problem waiting process.
I have run process.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()).start();
process.waitFor();
```

process.waitFor() not work :(
how i can wait like external processes.
Pleas help me.

Comment: "not work well" is not a problem statement: do you receive an error? Or does it not wait how you would expect? What do you expect?

Comment: no i have not get any error

Comment: not work well means not work waitfor()

Comment: It's because of the way IE runs.  If you call it from a batch file, you'll notice that the batch file returns immediately.

Comment: So do you mean problem is waiting IE?

Comment: It's the way most desktop apps run.

Comment: i need solution. please who can help me?